# SET unique ID for multiple rows on one form submit in sql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 4 columns and multiple rows.

The first column „ID“ is set to be „0“ as default for each row.

Now, I want to UPDATE this table and SET „ID“ to be unique number for multiple rows, which match the specific query created by one submit in my form.

The point is, that ID number has to have the same value as other rows with submited parameters. The ID number should be automatically generated, but it can’t be 0 and it has to be unique for each query.

Example:

[image]

So, on submit it should generate ID for each row with these parameters. These parameters are already in my table, I just want to assign same ID.

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Create a separate table for each submission with an auto increment id field. When a form gets submitted, then first insert a record into this table and get a unique id. Then use this id to create the batch of records in the other table.

Comment: That should work. And, how can I write UPDATE my_table and SET for column_1 number, which is not null and is unique in all column?

Comment: Not update, but insert. Do this when you insrert a new record, not after inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

insert into table(c2,c3,c4) (select IFNULL(1,Max(c1)+1),5,5 from table);

If your table is empty or first column is null then this query will insert 1 ,If it's not then it will get maximum value from the first column and add 1 . then it'll insert row into your table .